# Need help connecting and inserting data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I need some help with mongodb.

I just started using it, and made a Cluster called db, with a database called discord-bot with a collection called users

This should make a database entry for every user, so here is my code

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const uri = "mongodb+srv://<My username>:<My password>@<My db url>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run(query) {
    try {
        await client.connect();
        const database = client.db('discord-bot');
        const collection = database.collection('users');

        await collection.insertOne(query);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}

botClient.users.cache.forEach(u => {
    const q = { name: u.username }
    run(q).catch(console.dir);
})
```

I think this code should work, but it is giving me this error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'maxWireVersion' of null

I can not find anything online about that error, can somebody help me figure out what that error is and how to fix it. (Also, i am using mongodb with discord.js, incase that is neccessary info)

Comment: Try appending `&authSource=admin` on the string.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to connect to mongo DB

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var connection;
MongoClient.connect('your-db-uri', { useUnifiedTopology: true }, async function(err, client) {
    if(err)throw err
    console.log("Successfully Connected")
    connection = client
})
```

Then you can use connection variable as global for all functions